# British pound symbol (£) and php htmlentities to prevent XSS

Tags: php, xss, html-entities

I have an html form where the user can put in a currency symbol. When the form is first submitted using the £ symbol it save correctly, but when the form reloads the value is `&pound;`

So the second time it is saved it saves the entity and not the value

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($currency_symbol); ?>" />
```

I am using htmlentities to prevent XSS, but this seems to be a problem. Any ideas?

Comment: £ is the British pound, you probably want € *twitch*

Comment: Sorry, I meant British pound

Comment: You mention that the form "reloads", can you explain that? Why is it reloaded? Is it, for instance if there where some errors and you sent the user to the form again with the information prefilled?

Comment: This is a form that is used to save configuration information. The first time it saves correctly, but after going back to the form to update the information, the form value is &pound;

Comment: Sounds like you are doing double encoding